# select true/false based on col value in a group by

Tags: sql-server

Sorry if the title is not clear. I have a simple table `T1`

```
counter int, not null
type   nvarchar(250), not null
name   nvarchar(50),  not null
```

I'm summing up the counters grouped by type, Like this:

```
select sum(counter), type
    from T1
    group by type;
```

I want to select one more field which is boolean (true/false) which is any of the names contains a specific text i.e. if `name like '%Bassem%'` then select true. But I can not figure it out since I'm using group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this.

First create a test table and insert some values:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    [counter] int not null,
    [type] nvarchar(250) not null,
    [name] nvarchar(50) not null
);

INSERT INTO dbo.T ([counter], [type], [name])
    VALUES (1, N'Alpha', N'Bassem Akl'),
        (2, N'Alpha', N'aaaaa'),
        (3, N'Alpha', N'Akl Bassem'),
        (4, N'Bravo', N'bbbbb'),
        (5, N'Bravo', N'A Bassem'),
        (6, N'Charlie', N'ccccc'),
        (7, N'Charlie', N'ddddd');
```

Then use a CTE (common table expression) to determine if the name contains the text you are searching for. You don't have to use a CTE here, but it makes the overall SELECT statement easier to understand.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [counter], [type], IIF([name] LIKE N'%Bassem%', 1, 0) AS 'contains'
        FROM dbo.T
)
SELECT SUM([counter]) AS 'SumCounter', [type], CAST(MAX([contains]) AS bit) as 'contains'
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY [type];
```

[image]

Note that Transact-SQL doesn't have a Boolean data type; instead it has a bit type. See Books Online > bit (Transact-SQL) -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177603.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: I thought using cte will drop the performance down because the second select but strangely the otherwise happened I do not know why!!

Comment: Glad it helped! :-) I like CTEs a lot, because they make SQL statements much clearer. Have a look at the graphical execution plan and you should see that the Query Optimizer is not treating the CTE as a separate statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing to the graphical execution plan. First time to know about that.

Comment: Two good books about graphical execution plans are: SQL Server Execution Plans by Grant Fitchey, and Inside the SQL Server Query Optimizer by Benjamin Nevarez. Both e-books are available as free PDF downloads from Red Gate at: http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/

Comment: This is so much more than I hoped to get by this question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(counter), type,
max(case when name like '%value%' then true else false end ) as 'Booleanvalue'
  from T1
group by type;
```

you can do this as well,but you may want to do a distinct later using cte or derived table

```
select sum(counter) over (partition by type order by type),
      type,
 case when name like '%value%' then true else false end  as 'Booleanvalue'
from table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first method works for me after changing true/false into 1/0.

Comment: Glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte as
(
    SELECT counter, type, IIF(name like '%Bassem%', 1, 0) as b
    FROM #t
)
select sum(counter), type, CAST(max(b) as bit)
    from cte
    group by type;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CASE statement gets it done.

```
SELECT  SUM(foo.counter)
      , type
      , CASE WHEN foo.type = 'type a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS true_false
FROM  (VALUES (1, 'type a'), (2, 'type b')) AS foo(counter, type)
GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: I will test this solution to see how it works after these changes `foo.type like '%type a'` and `(0, 'type b')`. Thanks